# Error after reinstalling Eclipse and Java. Error in build path

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, buildpath

I have been programming in Eclipse for a coupe of weeks. I had to remove Eclipse and Java for software update.  However after I reinstalled Eclipse (Indigo) and Java Jdk (Java SE 8 (MacOS X Default)) I started to get errors.

The printer, scanner and object oriented programming method works fine but the Swing Components throw errors. Everytime I use method such as  `this.add(confirmButton);` I get errors. The Error is :

> The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly  referenced from required .class files.

The internet suggested to fix the Build Path but I am only allowed to Use the default Java SE 8 because other execution environment gives an error

> No JREs in workspace compatible with specified execution environment: JavaSE-1.7.

Comment: Do you import Swing classes?

Comment: go to windows properties, build path, click on libraries tab. click on jdk/jre entry and click on remove. click on add library. select java system (or something like that) pick the required jdk version, click apply and ok

Comment: I don't know whether you meant to attach an 'android' tag to this question; if so, note that there is no Swing in the android UI.

Comment: Yes I imported the swing classes. And about the android tag, I know it's irrelevent. please ignore.

Comment: i did that. went to the build path and removed the libraries and tried to select the JRE system Library, then under execution environment I cannot select any of the environments as it shows - No JREs in workspace compatible with specified execution environment: ... @Hector

Comment: Indigo does not work with Java 8. You have to use a newer Eclipse, such as Luna. Not sure if this is the error, though, as I think that this should raise _way_ more errors. Are you sure you are still using Eclipse indigo?

Comment: When you can update your Java SDK to Java8, why not use an updated version of eclipse also. Both Kepler and Luna are Java 8 compatibles.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is the problem, but as far as I know, Eclipse Indigo is *way* to old -- four year by now! It was outdated even before Java 8 arrived and never got support (like Kepler got, via a patch) for the new language features, such as default methods on interfaces and the like.

If you want to use Java 8, you should use a newer version of Eclipse. The current version that will properly work with Java 8 is Eclipse Luna (4.4).

Comment: Thank you so much. I installed the lates Eclipse Lune and everything works fine now. I guess the problem was that the Eclipse Indigo was configured to support the Java 8. Thank you guys.